# Why does my RewriteCond match even though the pattern clearly doesn't match?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Take a look at my rewrite log:

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css
(3) applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri '/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css'
(4) RewriteCond: input='${REQUEST_URI}' pattern='!^/app\.php' => matched
(4) RewriteCond: input='${REQUEST_URI}' pattern='!^/bundles/' => matched
(2) rewrite '/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css' -> '/app.php/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css'
(2) local path result: /app.php/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css
(2) prefixed with document_root to /srv/spectacle/web/app.php/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css
(1) go-ahead with /srv/spectacle/web/app.php/bundles/astrupsspectacle/spectacle.css [OK]
```

It says `pattern='!^/bundles/' => matched` even though it **clearly** doesn't. My pattern is:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^/bundles/
```

But I have also tried:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^bundles/
```

and even:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^bundles
```

And they all say "matched". What the hell!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong symbol for the environment variable. It should be `%` instead of `$`. So the condition should be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bundles/
```

Comment: I should add that it took me about 5 re-readings of the post to find that...

Comment: FINALLY!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!